# How can I multiply the elements in this array?

Tags: arrays, product

The goal is to multiply together all of the elements from 1 to `n`. I can get an array of these numbers, but need to multiply them together:

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

factorialize(5);
```

How can I return a product of my array?

Comment: Pull out each element and multiply it by the product of all the previous elements. Return the final result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this situation I guess we can put the .reduce method to a good use to get the product of the array in a quick manner.

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        array.push(i);
  }
  return array.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a * b;
  });
}

factorialize(5);
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sak6hkab/

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the issue by building an array of numbers prior to multiplying. That array serves no real purpose here. This is a simple recursion, but you should be wary (no matter what solution you use) of what you're doing if the number passed is zero or less:

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num <= 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return (num * factorialize(num - 1));
  }
}

factorialize(5);
```